# Python code structure & convention - Creating a elements for a list with a loop

Tags: python

I've been reading some articles at python-guide.org and revisiting some of my code to clean it up and get in to good habits. In one of my programs I want to generate a list of odd numbers within a range defined by the user:

```
i = 3
while i <= limit:
    #Test whether the number is odd by checking remainder is not 0
    if i % 2 != 0:
        integers.append(i)
    i += 1
```

In one of the articles on python-guide the author says that this isn't the best way to create elements for a list (it's classed as bad), so by expanding the good example that's provided I've come up with this:

```
integers = [int(n) for n in range(2, limit + 1) if (n is 2) or (n % 2 != 0)]
```

They both produce the same output, but would the second example be classed as a bit nuts? Is there too much going on in one statement?

Thanks for your thoughts,
Pete

Comment: Note:  Doing `(n is 2)` is wrong. The `is` operator is used to compare the _identity_ of two objects.  You should use `==` to compare values.

Comment: List comprehensions are considered more "python-esque", and the shorter one in Óscar López answer is very clear as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This list comprehension:

```
integers = [int(n) for n in range(2, limit + 1) if (n is 2) or (n % 2 != 0)]
```

Can be further simplified:

```
integers = [2] + [n for n in range(3, limit+1) if n % 2]
```

Explanation:

- You don't need to convert `n` to an `int`, it's *already* an integer
- You should use `==` to compare numbers for equality, instead of `is`. And anyway, it's a better idea to get that condition out of the loop, it's true only *once* for the whole iteration. I'd rather append the number two at the beginning
- The expression `n % 2 != 0` as a conditional is equivalent to `n % 2`, because in Python `0` is considered falsy and any other non-zero value is truthy

Alternatively, you could modify the list in-place to add the missing number at the beginning (this should be a bit more efficient):

```
integers = [n for n in range(3, limit+1) if n % 2]
integers.insert(0, 2)
```

And no, this would not be classified as nuts. It's the idiomatic way to create lists in Python, it's even *faster* (performance-wise) than writing a explicit loop.

Comment: are you sure?
`>>> limit = 10
>>> [int(n) for n in range(2, limit + 1) if (n is 2) or (n % 2 != 0)]
**[2, 3, 5, 7, 9]**
>>> [n for n in range(2, limit+1) if n % 2]
**[3, 5, 7, 9]**`

Comment: That's what I had originally but I needed the number 2 to be the first element in the list which is why (n is 2) had to be included in the if statement... then it got out of hand.

Comment: For further reading on python conventions, read the PEP8: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Well 2 isn't odd, why do you want it in the list?

Comment: @William it's for a Prime Sieve

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing wrong with your list comprehension.

You are using `n is 2` instead of `n == 2`. This is not even needed in your list comprehension (See @ÓscarLópez's answer), but for clarity's sake, here it is.

`is` compares the **identities** of two things:

```
>>> id(a)
4298180600
>>> id(9)
4298180600
>>> a is 9
True
>>>
```

However, this is **not** the same as `==`, which just checks if they are the same, not taking in `id`s.

For example, `==` says the below is the same (correct response), but `is` says the contrary:

```
>>> [1] == [2-1]
True
>>> [1] is [2-1]
False
>>> [2-1]
[1]
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> foo = 10
>>> dir(foo) == dir(10)
True
>>> dir(foo) is dir(10)
False
>>>
```